# Search for link and click it

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have managed to get it work with SendKeys. However it is not the best solution to navigate web page with SendKeys. I have been trying to get this code working with no success. It opens the web page and nothing happens.

Link class: `class="a_1_610"`

Link text: `Dashboard`

From source code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="nowrap"><span class="h_1_610" style="display: none;">Dashboard</span>
      <a href="DA3192.html" class="a_1_610" >
      Dashboard</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
```

`DA3192.html` is changing all the time. Next time you navigate to web page it is `DA3672.html` or something.

The problem is that all the links have `class="a_1_610"`. So I have tried to catch it by link text, but it does not seem to work (nothing happens). Website is not available for public, only private use so there is no possibility to share it. Are there any other ways to make it work other than SendKeys?

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
'Set appIE = Nothing
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://mysite/"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

    Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each hyper_link In objCollection
    If hyper_link.innerText = "Dashboard" Then
    hyper_link.Click
    Exit For

    End If
    Next

Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There is almost certainly a better, faster, way than looping all the a tags. Can you share the page html using https://pastebin.com/ ? As a minimum the table html. Is the link always in the same row and column in the table for example? Is it the only href ending with .html in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to see if innertext is with "bug" and have blank caracteres , use LIKE and wildcard.

```
   For Each hyper_link In objCollection
         If vba.Lcase(hyper_link.innerText) like "*dashboard*" Then
                 hyper_link.Click
                 Exit For
         end if
```

Tell me if it works!

Comment: Wow! It actually works. How about if I have `Project Actuals and Forecast` instead of `Dashboard`?

Comment: The same logic 
If vba.Lcase(hyper_link.innerText) like "*Project Acttuals and Forecast*" Then